# Does SharePoint 2013 support Single Sign Out?

Tags: 2013, claims-based-auth

Really simple question, that I can't seem to find a definitive answer for.

Does SharePoint 2013 support single sign-out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really mean Single-Sign-**Out**, then the answer is no. SharePoint is a web application and when you log out of SharePoint you're only logged out of that application and not all other system relying on e.g. your domain account.

There is no "message" transferred from SharePoint to "all" other systems that you logged out. The other way around: Signle-Sign-On is supported if you're using Claims Authentication or NTLM to login.

Comment: I do mean *out*. In a claims based environment in 2010 logging out didn't call https://<STS FQDN and PORT>/sts/ls?wa=wsignout1.0. I'm hoping 2013 does

Comment: Ah! You're talking about federated Sign-Out. Sorry, I didn't test this yet, but I would be surprised if they changed that mechanism especially for ADFS. There are several solutions available though to create your own logout link, like http://blogs.southworks.net/aortega/2010/08/13/sharepoint-2010-and-adfs-sign-in-as-a-different-user/

Comment: Sorry, my poor use of terminology. That explains why searching for Single Sign-Out was fruitless. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: (search for wsignout1.0 and sharepoint and you'll find several solutions)